# Encryption usage in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'd like to learn how to store different encrypted sensitive information of any kind, but unfortunately don't know how and where to start learning from. I can write whole of things in application except password encryption/protection. Can someone show me the right direction to look at? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks, correcteed my question.

Comment: that's a start although high-rep users are able to see edit history...

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use the [keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) to store the user/password?

Some tutorial and examples can be found [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html).

Comment: That's true, but probably not the best way to go if you'll be storing many username/password pairs.

Comment: What could be the best way? May be using Core Data?